# Powershell Http post request

Tags: powershell, post, http-post

Read over the stackoverflow for the answer, still can't find what causing this..

Trying to connect and send a POST request using powershell, and getting "unable to connect to remote server" error. Tried 3 different dummy servers like http://posttestserver.com/post.php

Script:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
[string]$url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php"
function Execute-HTTPPostCommand()
{
param([string]$target = $null)
#$username = "administrator"
#$password = "mypass"
$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($target)
$webRequest.ContentType = "text/html"
$post = "abcdefg"
$PostStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Post)
$webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStr.Length
$webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = $false
#$webRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password 
#$webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true
$webRequest.Method = "POST"
try
{
$requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
}
catch
{
write-host $_.Exception 
}
$requestStream.Write($PostStr, 0,$PostStr.length)
$requestStream.Close()
[System.Net.WebResponse]$resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
[System.IO.StreamReader]$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
[string]$results = $sr.ReadToEnd();
return $results;
}
Execute-HTTPPostCommand $url
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Sounds like this may be an issue on your system instead. Can you `nslookup posttestserver.com`?

Comment: nslookup works.. I am at work, so there could be proxi filtering post though.

Comment: Do you have access to another machine you could try from outside work? Might be worth a shot.

Also, as an aside, if you're using PowerShell 3.0+, you can drastically shrink your code: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post`

Comment: I know ivnoike-werbrequest would so much easier, but i am using powershell 1 :)